# The maximum weight in a weighted sum of Fibonacci squares representation of a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

**Theorem.** Every positive integer can be represented as a weighted sum of Fibonacci squares.

*Proof.* Start with a postive integer $N$. Obtain its unique sum of non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers representation (i.e., the [Zeckendorf representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem)). Now, rewrite the sum by replacing every Fibonacci number with Fibonacci squares using the following identities based on the index:

$$
\begin{align}
F_{2n+1} & = F_n^2 + F_{n+1}^2 &; \text{ for odd indices } \\
F_{2n}   & = F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2 + \overbrace{F_{2(n-1)}}^\text{reduced even index} &; \text{ for even indices } 
\end{align}
$$

We can recursively apply the identities to the reduction of $F_{2(n-1)}$ using the $F_{2n}$ identity until we are left with $F_1^2$ or $F_2^2$ when the recursion ends. For consistency, we can choose to represent $1$ as $F_1^2$.

This process results in a multiset of Fibonacci squares that can be summed to write $N$ as a weighted sum of Fibonacci squares.

$\blacksquare$

**Question:** What is the maximum weight possible in a sum of Fibonacci squares representation obtained using the process described above?

**Empirical data.**  Data for $1 .. 20000$ shows the maximum weight is $16$. Obviously, the maximum weight keeps growing as $N$ grows.

I think the maximum weight grows as $O(\log_{\phi} N)$ where $$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Is this correct?

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= 1 \times 1^2 \\
2 &= 2 \times 1^2 \\
3 &= 3 \times 1^2 \\
4 &= 4 \times 1^2 \\
5 &= 5 \times 1^2 \\
6 &= 2 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
7 &= 3 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
8 &= 4 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
9 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
10 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
11 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
12 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
13 &= 2 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
14 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
15 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
16 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
17 &= 1 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
18 &= 2 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
19 &= 2 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
20 &= 2 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
21 &= 2 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
22 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
23 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
24 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
25 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
26 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
27 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
28 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
29 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
30 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 9 \times 1^2 \\
31 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 10 \times 1^2 \\
32 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 11 \times 1^2 \\
33 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 \\
34 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
35 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
36 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
37 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
38 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
39 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
40 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
41 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
42 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
43 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
44 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
45 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
46 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
47 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
48 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
49 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
50 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
51 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
52 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
53 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
54 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
55 &= 2 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
56 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
57 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
58 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
59 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
60 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
61 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
62 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
63 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
64 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 9 \times 1^2 \\
65 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 10 \times 1^2 \\
66 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 11 \times 1^2 \\
67 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 \\
68 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
69 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
70 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
71 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
72 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
73 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
74 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
75 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
76 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 8 \times 1^2 \\
77 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 9 \times 1^2 \\
78 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 10 \times 1^2 \\
79 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 11 \times 1^2 \\
80 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 4 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 \\
81 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 9 \times 1^2 \\
82 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 10 \times 1^2 \\
83 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 11 \times 1^2 \\
84 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 \\
85 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 13 \times 1^2 \\
86 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 14 \times 1^2 \\
87 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 15 \times 1^2 \\
88 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 16 \times 1^2 \\
89 &= 2 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
90 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 1^2 \\
91 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 2 \times 1^2 \\
92 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 1^2 \\
93 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
94 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
95 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 2 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
96 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 2^2 \\
97 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 4 \times 1^2 \\
98 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
99 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 6 \times 1^2 \\
100 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2 + 1 \times 2^2 + 7 \times 1^2 \\
\cdots \\
19997 &= 1 \times 89^2 + 2 \times 55^2 + 3 \times 34^2 + 4 \times 21^2 + 3 \times 13^2 + 2 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 5^2 + 5 \times 3^2 + 6 \times 2^2 + 15 \times 1^2 \\
19998 &= 1 \times 89^2 + 2 \times 55^2 + 3 \times 34^2 + 4 \times 21^2 + 3 \times 13^2 + 2 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 5^2 + 5 \times 3^2 + 6 \times 2^2 + 16 \times 1^2 \\
19999 &= 1 \times 89^2 + 2 \times 55^2 + 3 \times 34^2 + 4 \times 21^2 + 3 \times 13^2 + 2 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 5^2 + 5 \times 3^2 + 7 \times 2^2 + 13 \times 1^2 \\
20000 &= 1 \times 89^2 + 2 \times 55^2 + 3 \times 34^2 + 4 \times 21^2 + 3 \times 13^2 + 2 \times 8^2 + 3 \times 5^2 + 5 \times 3^2 + 7 \times 2^2 + 14 \times 1^2 \\
\cdots
\end{align}
$$

**Related:**

This line of inquiry came up while thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739616).

Comment: I do not underastand the example $4=4\cdot 1^2$. $4$ is the weight and it is not a fibonacci-number.

Comment: @Peter: The question has been edited. No longer looking for Fibonacci weights.

Comment: Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739616/1102817 can give some ideas? Here's one suggestion:
$$N = \sum_i x_iF_i^2 = \frac{1}{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)} \left[\left(\sum_i x_i F_i\right)^2 + \sum_j \sum_{i,\; i < j} (F_j - F_i)^2 x_j x_i \right]$$

Comment: Look at $F_{2n+1}-1$, for example $34-1=33$, or $89-1=88$

Comment: @Empy2: We have

$$
\begin{align}
33 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 \\
34 &= 1 \times 3^2 + 1 \times 5^2 \\
88 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 3^2 + 5 \times 2^2 + 16 \times 1^2 \\
89 &= 1 \times 5^2 + 1 \times 8^2
\end{align}
$$

Is your point that it is not $O(\log_{\phi} N)$ asymptotic growth rate for the maximal weight?

Comment: @Empy2: Although, your comment made me think that we can rewrite the coefficient of $1^2$ in terms of the other higher powers using Euclidean algorithm. For eg: $33 = 1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 12 \times 1^2 = 2 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 2^2 + 3 \times 1^2$.

Comment: I meant that, if the rule goes via the Zeckendorf representation, we seem to get an extra four 1s every time - 4,12,33,88 have 4,8,12,16 ones.

Comment: After $2^2=4×1$, each square is less than three times the next one down, so you can do Eucliden algorithm with only the coefficient of $1^2$ as high as three.  For example $33=5^2+2×2^2$

Comment: So, we can do an extra Euclidean step with the coefficient $a_1$ in $N = a_m \times F_m^2 + \cdots + a_k \times F_k^2 + a_1 \times 1^2$ iff $a_1 \ge F_k^2$ and no Fibonacci number with index in the range $(3, k-1)$ is in the representation.