# Factoring an integer using its Zeckendorf representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, fibonacci-numbers

**Notation:**

Given an integer $N$, we find its Zeckendorf representation as the sum of non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers. By the Zeckendorf theorem, this representation is unique.

Let $\zeta_N$ denote the ordered sequence of the Fibonacci numbers in the Zeckendorf representation of $N$. The number of Fibonacci numbers (i.e., digits) in the Zeckendorf representation is $O(\log_{\phi}{N})$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio.

We define the following functions on a sequence $S$:

1. $\mu$ computes the minimum nonzero element in the sequence $S$.

$$
\begin{align}
\mu(S) &= \min(x) : {x\in S,x \ne 0}
\end{align}
$$

2. $\gamma$ returns the non-trivial factor of $N$ if it is contained in $S$ (or returns $1$ otherwise).

$$
\begin{align}
\gamma(S) &= \begin{cases}
   \gcd(x,N), & \text{if $\exists x \in S$ s.t. $\gcd(x,N) \ne 1$}\\
            1, & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

3. $\delta$ rebalances the sequence by subtracting $\mu(S_k)$ from each non-zero element in $S_k$:

$$
\begin{align}
\delta(x) &= 
\begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
  \mu(S_{k})n, & \text{if $x = \mu(S_k), n = $ number of non-zero entries in $S_k$} \\
  x - \mu(S_{k}), & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}, \\
x &\in S_{k}
\end{align}
$$ and

4. we define the recurrence

$$
S_{k+1} = \langle \delta(x) : x \in S_{k} \rangle
$$
We set $S_0 = \zeta_N$ and iteratively compute $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_k$. After computing each $S_i$, we check if $\gamma(S_i) \ne 1$ and stop if that is true.

---

**Empirical testing:**

I wrote a small program that does this and tested it on small $N$. Surprisingly, it seems to find the non-trivial factor.

Here's an example:

```
1:  Zeckendorf(1387) =
2:   (987, 16),
3:   (377, 14),
4:   (21, 8),
5:   (2, 3)
6:   [Size: 4 terms]
7:  Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1387 = 1387 (check)
8:  After subtraction: 985, 375, 19, 8
9:  Found factors 19x73 in 1 iterations
10: Found factors 19x73 = 1387
```

Lines 2-5 show the Zeckendorf representation of $1387 = 987 + 377 + 21 + 2$. The pair $(987, 16)$ is of the form $(F_n, n)$.

Here's a step-by-step of what happens with the algorithm:

1. We have $N=1387=987 + 377 + 21 + 2$.
2. The minimal non-zero element is $2$. None of these elements have a non-trivial GCD with $N=1387$. So, we proceed to the next step.
3. We subtract the minimal non-zero element $2$ from all non-zero elements that are not $2$ and add the total subtracted to $2$.
4. i.e. We get $N=1387=(987 - 2) + (377 - 2) + (21 - 2) + (2 + 2 + 2 + 2) = 985 + 375 + 19 + 8$.
5. Since $19|1387$, we report it as a factor and it took just one iteration.

---

Here is an example that takes 5 iterations to find the factor:

```
Zeckendorf(1216669) =
  (832040, 30),
  (317811, 28),
  (46368, 24),
  (17711, 22),
  (2584, 18),
  (144, 12),
  (8, 6),
  (3, 4)
  [Size: 8 terms]
Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1216669 = 1216669 (check)
After iter #0: 832040, 317811, 46368, 17711, 2584, 144, 8, 3
After iter #1: 832037, 317808, 46365, 17708, 2581, 141, 5, 24
After iter #2: 832032, 317803, 46360, 17703, 2576, 136, 40, 19
After iter #3: 832013, 317784, 46341, 17684, 2557, 117, 21, 152
After iter #4: 831992, 317763, 46320, 17663, 2536, 96, 168, 131
Found factors in 1039x1171 in 5 iterations
Found factors 1039x1171 = 1216669
```

We can check that $GCD(17663, 1216669) = 1039$.

It is not short like the example with $N=1387$ and shows how each iteration progresses.

---

I ran the program on $625$ products of those primes ($25$ primes greater than $1000$) and in each instance the factors were found. Some more examples:

```
Zeckendorf(1018081) = 
  (832040, 30),
  (121393, 26),
  (46368, 24),
  (17711, 22),
  (377, 14),
  (144, 12),
  (34, 9),
  (13, 7),
  (1, 2)
  [Size: 9 terms]
Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1018081 = 1018081 (check)
Found factors in 1009x1009 in 15 iterations
Found factors 1009x1009 = 1018081
Zeckendorf(1022117) = 
  (832040, 30),
  (121393, 26),
  (46368, 24),
  (17711, 22),
  (4181, 19),
  (377, 14),
  (34, 9),
  (13, 7)
  [Size: 8 terms]
Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1022117 = 1022117 (check)
Found factors in 1013x1009 in 66 iterations
Found factors 1013x1009 = 1022117
Zeckendorf(1028171) = 
  (832040, 30),
  (121393, 26),
  (46368, 24),
  (17711, 22),
  (6765, 20),
  (2584, 18),
  (987, 16),
  (233, 13),
  (89, 11),
  (1, 2)
  [Size: 10 terms]
Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1028171 = 1028171 (check)
Found factors in 1009x1019 in 112 iterations
Found factors 1009x1019 = 1028171
Zeckendorf(1030189) = 
  (832040, 30),
  (196418, 27),
  (1597, 17),
  (89, 11),
  (34, 9),
  (8, 6),
  (3, 4)
  [Size: 7 terms]
Sum(Zeta(N)) = 1030189 = 1030189 (check)
Found factors in 1021x1009 in 26 iterations
Found factors 1021x1009 = 1030189
```

This is a scatterplot of the *number of iterations* to find the factor vs. $N$.

[image: Scatterplot of iterations vs. N]

**Observations:**

1. Here are some of the statistics from the run:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Count:} & 625 \\
\text{Minimum:} & 1 \\
\text{Maximum:} & 658 \\
\text{Average:} & 82.5264 \\
\text{Stdev:}   & 90.3744
\end{matrix}
$$

2. Statistics broken down by whether $N$ is a square or not. Interestingly, squares seem to have a lot of variance and the average is also $\gt 2\times$ the non-squares. Fortunately, it is easy to check for a square before attempting factorization. So, I am not concerned about this.

[image: Stats breakdown by N being square or not]

3. The fact that the scatterplot shows some  points (asymptotically) closer to $\sqrt{N}$ means that this may still have worst case behavior in $O(\sqrt{N})$ i.e., no better than trial division.
4. Scatter plot of $n$, number of iterations vs. $d$, number of digits in Fibonacci square base *(See updates below)*

[image: Scatter plot of n, number of iterations vs. d, number of digits in Fibonacci square base]

---

**Updates:**

1. (July 29, 2023): A straightforward optimization that we can do is compute $\mu(S)$ and $\theta(S)$ where $\theta(S) = \mu(S\backslash \{\mu(S)\})$ i.e., the second smallest element in $S$. We can then subtract the smallest multiple of $\mu(S)$ from $\theta(S)$ so that

$$
\theta(S) - \alpha \cdot \mu(S) \lt \alpha \cdot \mu(S) \\
\implies \theta(S) \lt 2 \alpha \cdot \mu(S) \\
\implies \alpha \gt \frac{\theta(S)}{2\mu(S)}
$$

> **(Update after testing):** This doesn't necessarily work as it also skips over the GCD computation on the sequence elements resulting in sub-optimal number of iterations.

2. (July 29, 2023): **An exciting update.** The method seems to also work with weighted Fibonacci squares decomposition i.e.,

$$N = \sum (F_{c_i}^{2} \cdot w_i) \text{ where $c_i, w_i, i \in \mathbb{Z}$ }$$.

I had a [related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739998) on weighted Fibonacci squares decomposition here. The good news is every positive integer has a weighted Fibonacci squares sum decomposition.

In fact, it performs better, empirically on the same test data.

[image: Scatter plot of iterations for Fibonacci squares decomposition]

Here is the comparison summary between using the Zeckendorf representation versus the weighted Fibonacci squares representation:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Squares better?} & \text{Count} & \text{pct. of total} \newline
\text{TRUE} & 382 & 61\% \newline
\text{FALSE} & 243 & 39\% \newline
\text{Total} & 625 & 100\%
\end{matrix}
$$

On 61% of cases Fibonacci squares do better and on the remaining the Fibonacci numbers do better. The average and standard deviation is also markedly better.

4. (July 29, 2023): **Another interesting update.** If we use the partition of $N$ as the sum of powers of $2$, then the algorithm works. I am going to conjecture that any base $b$ would work. **Perhaps, there is a base $b$ dependent on $N$ that is optimal for factoring $N$ using this algorithm (also a conjecture).**

[image: Scatter plot of n vs. d for powers of 2 base]

**Questions:**

1. Why does this algorithm even work? Can we show a proof for why it should work (or not)?
2. If this does work, are there any ideas for improving the runtime complexity?

Comment: Interesting !  I tried your method to factorize $N=64699508268589=200029*323450641$ successfully within $9228$ iterations.

Comment: @user295357: Yes. Zeckendorf sum gives $9229$ iterations and Fibonacci squares sum gives it in $3737$ iterations. I am also counting the first GCD check on the Zeckendorf or Fibonacci squares sum.

Comment: How do you do if $N$ happens to be a Fibonacci number (e.g.,  $N=21$) ?

Comment: @user295357: That's a good observation. But there is a workaround. We use the Fibonacci identity and split the $F_n$ into *three* integers (apply the identity twice) and then run the algorithm. Here's the log from my program after I split $21 = 3 + 5 + 13$ and voila $3$ is a factor of $21$.
$$
\text{After iter #0: 3, 5, 13}\\
\text{Found factors in 3x7 in 1 iterations. The number of digits is 3}\\
\text{Found factors 3x7 = 21}
$$

So, I guess, there is a *for a sufficiently large N* qualifier somewhere that we need to apply.

Comment: Interestingly, just splitting $21 = 8 + 13$ doesn't work. The program enters an infinite loop. So, we need at least $3$ *digits*. That brings an interesting question for Fibonacci squares representation. What do we do if we have a Fibonacci square? It looks like we can partition an integer into any $3$ or more integers and run the algorithm. I posted a separate question on 3-partitions of $N$ and factoring.

Comment: Link to related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744394

Comment: An astonishing method that can possibly compete with Pollard-rho.