# Factoring an integer $N$ using its random partition of length $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, integer-partitions

While working on [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744025) that I had posted, I wondered what would be a minimal base of numbers that we could work with the algorithm described in that question.

I *conjectured* that a partition of $N$ into $3$ integers may be a good place to start.

> **Update:** This conjecture is true to the extent that a partition of size $2$ is not guaranteed to work. Based on the observation that if $N = F_n$, i.e., a Fibonacci number, the Zeckendorf representation has just one *digit*, $F_n$ and we cannot proceed further. But, there is a workaround by using the Fibonacci identity $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$ and we can apply the identity twice to get at least $3$ non-zero *digits*. For example, the partition $21 = 13 + 8$ doesn't work as the recurrence goes on infinitely. But, if we split it as $21 = 13 + 5 + 3$, we get the factor $3$ in the first iteration itself. Thanks to [user295357](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/841899/user295357) for their comment in the linked question that brought this up.

So, on similar lines as the linked question, we define the recurrence for the triple $(a_k, b_k, c_k)$:

$$
\begin{align}
a_k&=\min(3a_{k-1},b_{k-1}-a_{k-1},c_{k-1}-a_{k-1}) \\
c_k&=\max⁡(3a_{k-1},b_{k-1}-a_{k-1},c_{k-1}-a_{k-1} ) \\
b_k&=N-a_k-c_k
\end{align}
$$

Note that the triple has the property that $\forall k \ge 0, a_k < b_k < c_k$.

We initialize $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ with a *random partition* of $N$ satisfying $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt c_0$.

We check if the set $\{\gcd⁡(a_k,N),\gcd⁡(b_k,N),\gcd⁡(c_k,N)\}$ contains an element greater than $1$, i.e., a non-trivial divisor of $N$. If yes, we stop. Otherwise, we apply the recurrence and try again.

---

I wrote a program to test it. This algorithm works in finding the non-trivial divisor based on empirical testing. Same test set as used in the linked question (25 primes greater than 1000 are taken and their pair products are used as $N$, including squares).

The question of *why this algorithm works?* and a proof (or counterexample) request is already there [in the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744025). So, we don't need to go into it here (Feel free to drop a comment or an answer to the linked question there).

In this question, I am asking **if there is an optimal choice of partitioning $N$ into $3$ integers such that the number of iterations $n$ taken to reach algorithm termination is minimal.**

> As @[Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin) points out in the comments, choosing $d|N$ and the partition $(d, 2d, N-3d)$ will be optimal. I am asking what our partition choice should be given $d$ is unknown and $N$ is not easily factorable. *minimal* should be interpreted in that context.

---

**Empirical testing data:**

The following scatterplot shows the number of iterations for the dataset using the initial partition set to

$$(a_0, b_0, c_0) = \big(\lfloor \sqrt{N}/2 \rfloor, \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor, N - \lfloor \sqrt{N}/2 \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor\big)$$

[image: Scatterplot of N vs n]

This is the scatterplot with the initial partition

$$(a_0, b_0, c_0) = (1, 2, N - 1 - 2)$$

[image: Scatterplot of N vs n - different initial parameters]

Program output for $N = 1402627 = 1249 \times 1123$:

```
At iteration 1: (1, 2, 1402624)
At iteration 2: (1, 3, 1402623)
At iteration 3: (2, 3, 1402622)
At iteration 4: (1, 6, 1402620)
At iteration 5: (3, 5, 1402619)
At iteration 6: (2, 9, 1402616)
At iteration 7: (6, 7, 1402614)
At iteration 8: (1, 18, 1402608)
At iteration 9: (3, 17, 1402607)
At iteration 10: (9, 14, 1402604)
At iteration 11: (5, 27, 1402595)
At iteration 12: (15, 22, 1402590)
At iteration 13: (7, 45, 1402575)
At iteration 14: (21, 38, 1402568)
At iteration 15: (17, 63, 1402547)
At iteration 16: (46, 51, 1402530)
At iteration 17: (5, 138, 1402484)
At iteration 18: (15, 133, 1402479)
At iteration 19: (45, 118, 1402464)
At iteration 20: (73, 135, 1402419)
At iteration 21: (62, 219, 1402346)
At iteration 22: (157, 186, 1402284)
At iteration 23: (29, 471, 1402127)
At iteration 24: (87, 442, 1402098)
At iteration 25: (261, 355, 1402011)
At iteration 26: (94, 783, 1401750)
At iteration 27: (282, 689, 1401656)
At iteration 28: (407, 846, 1401374)
At iteration 29: (439, 1221, 1400967)
At iteration 30: (782, 1317, 1400528)
At iteration 31: (535, 2346, 1399746)
At iteration 32: (1605, 1811, 1399211)
At iteration 33: (206, 4815, 1397606)
At iteration 34: (618, 4609, 1397400)
At iteration 35: (1854, 3991, 1396782)
At iteration 36: (2137, 5562, 1394928)
At iteration 37: (3425, 6411, 1392791)
At iteration 38: (2986, 10275, 1389366)
At iteration 39: (7289, 8958, 1386380)
At iteration 40: (1669, 21867, 1379091)
At iteration 41: (5007, 20198, 1377422)
At iteration 42: (15021, 15191, 1372415)
At iteration 43: (170, 45063, 1357394)
At iteration 44: (510, 44893, 1357224)
At iteration 45: (1530, 44383, 1356714)
At iteration 46: (4590, 42853, 1355184)
At iteration 47: (13770, 38263, 1350594)
At iteration 48: (24493, 41310, 1336824)
At iteration 49: (16817, 73479, 1312331)
At iteration 50: (50451, 56662, 1295514)
At iteration 51: (6211, 151353, 1245063)
At iteration 52: (18633, 145142, 1238852)
At iteration 53: (55899, 126509, 1220219)
At iteration 54: (70610, 167697, 1164320)
At iteration 55: (97087, 211830, 1093710)
At iteration 56: (114743, 291261, 996623)
At iteration 57: (176518, 344229, 881880)
At iteration 58: (167711, 529554, 705362)
At iteration 59: (361843, 503133, 537651)
At iteration 60: (141290, 175808, 1085529)
At iteration 61: (34518, 423870, 944239)
At iteration 62: (103554, 389352, 909721)
At iteration 63: (285798, 310662, 806167)
At iteration 64: (24864, 520369, 857394)
At iteration 65: (74592, 495505, 832530)
At iteration 66: (223776, 420913, 757938)
Found factors in 1249x1123 in 66 iterations.
Found factors 1249x1123 = 1402627
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by "choice". If $d$ is a nontrivial factor of $N$ then (in most cases) $d+2d+(N-3d)$ is an optimal choice—no iterations are needed.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. If we magically had $d$ there is no problem to solve. But $d$ is unknown and say $N$ is large. The question is not about existence of such $d$. Knowing that we can't easily choose $d$ (without factoring it another way), how do we choose the partition so that we can find the factor $d$ quickly?

Comment: It feels premature to ask about optimizing the input when one doesn't even know how to select an input that guarantees termination in the first place.

Comment: If we can characterize inputs that do terminate in some $n$ steps, that would be great. At the moment, the algorithm is only conjectured to terminate although it seems to do so for small $N$ that has been tested.